# Instagram Popup followers list scroll down

Tags: python, web-scraping, scroll, instagram

I want to print list of followers names from the instagram followers list. But it only scroll down and doesnot print more then 7 followers names in the console. Here is my code:

```
def another_user_followers(browser, acc_username, no_of_followers_to_follow):
signIn(browser)
search_box = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/input")
    )
)
search_box.send_keys(acc_username)
time.sleep(1)
search_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(1)
search_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(2)
try:
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector(
        "#react-root > section > main > div > header > section > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a").click()
except:
    print("This Account is Private or It is a Tag")
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/a/div/div").click()
    sys.exit()
time.sleep(2)
browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/button").click()
time.sleep(2)
browser.find_element_by_css_selector(
    "#react-root > section > main > div > header > section > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a").click()
for i in range(1, no_of_followers_to_follow):
    followers_list = []
    str1 = "/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/ul/div/li["
    str2 = "]/div/div[3]"
    final_string = str1 + str(i) + str2
    a = browser.find_element_by_xpath(final_string)
    if i % 6 == 0:

        followedPopup = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='isgrP']")
        browser.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollTop + arguments[0].offsetHeight;',followedPopup)
        time.sleep(1)
        followers_list.append(a.text)
        time.sleep(1)
        print(followers_list)
    else:
        followers_list.append(a.text)
        time.sleep(1)
        print(followers_list)
```

Here is the error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/ul/div/li[7]/div/div[3]"}
```

(Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.149)

What is wrong with my code? i wish to print 100 followers in the console. But it only print 6 names

Comment: Use ```css selectors``` instead of ```XPATH``` because css selector will return accurate results, but XPATH's tend to change when you scroll down the page. If you don't believe me then inspect XPATH of the page manually.

Answer (score 0):

better target the specific class than parsing from html and while
using find_element_by_xpath should start with the 2 forward slashes ('//')

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//html...')
```